# How to run graphical python program on Ubuntu server?

Tags: python, gui, opencv

I am working on face recognition project on Ubuntu 18.04 remote server. I don't know how to install the desktop(GUI) version. I can run face recognition program without the `cv2.imshow` part. How can I display the results in graphical mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are accessing the server remotely. If so (or if you can) see below.

For development you may want to look at using **jupyter notebook**. It runs on the server and you can access it from a web browser on another computer. You can wright you code or scripts in it and save/load programs there. The main thing is that over the remote browser session you can get images to appear so it may serve your needs. I've quite liked the tool from my use.

> The Jupyter Notebook is an open-source web application that allows you to create and share documents that contain live code, equations, visualizations and narrative text.

[jupyter](https://jupyter.org/)